# Terminology: Is it correct to refer to the spacetime interval as "absolute distance?"

Tags: spacetime, distance

...Because it's Lorentz-invariant.

Different inertial frames observe different distances, durations, and simultaneity. They even report a different time of day on their wristwatch. But everyone in any frame agrees on the interval.

So when I explain stuff to other people, can I refer to "4D absolute distance?"

Comment: The usual term is _proper distance_ for a spacelike interval or _proper time_ for a timelike interval. If you use those terms everyone will know what you mean.

Comment: @john Yes, but the interval is neither of those. Their sum is the invariant quantity.

Comment: it is a matter of semantics. If you want to call the spacetime interval 4D absolute distance, that is fine, but it is not a standard name, and most physicists will not be sure of what do you mean by that (they might guess though), unless you explain it.

Comment: John Rennie is correct, which is why his comment is being upvoted. Your comment is incorrect.

Comment: @pato "physicists will not be sure of what do you mean." Of course. I say "interval." But the commonry understands it, and that's my audience. Feynman said "mass" in his dissertation, but in popular lectures, he said "stuff."

Comment: @Miss_Understands I think it can create confusion on your audience. Think about the "4D absolute distance" of the path of a light right, it is zero. Or that of a spacelike interval, it will be imaginary! (or that of timelike distance, depending on how do you define the 4D AD)

Comment: @pato " "4D absolute distance" of the path of a light right, it is zero." Yes, and that's how we should think of it! Action at a distance isnt spooky when athe (absolute) distance is zero.

Comment: @Miss_Understands You are mixing unrelated things

Comment: I don't believe it's a coincidence that the gravitational interaction occurs on the null surface of massive objects. When you feel the tide, it can be seen as waves emitted from the moon 1 light-sec away, but I think it's equally valid to see it as you interacting now with the moon 1 second in the past. Remember, all mass carries with it it's own private "right now." Unfortunately, I don't understand the gravitational interaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saying that spacetime interval means interval "as absolute distance" it is not technically correct. Just as $ds^2$ is the invariant of spacetime, it always has the same value in all inertial frames, no matter how the frame changes. But the feeling on the contrary is that it is not at a distance (as normally understood).

Space-time interval contains both space and time dimensions in its formulas, and with them, it is a measure of the “distance” between events in space-time. Besides the spatial component, there's another element as well: it's time. In light of this, the only proper words to use here would be *spacetime interval* rather than "absolute distance" to better grasp the reality of this.

"Relative distance in 4D space" is too unclear because it partially represents the whole spacetime interval - the distance of an object in the present can be different (higher or lower) than the distance of the same object in the past or future all due to the transformation of the interval. Rather than using the top two terms, it is much safer to refer to it simply as the "spacetime interval" or the "invariant interval" to avoid misinterpretation.

Comment: accepted as best answer, question closed, ty!